I want Excel to recalculate the workbook when hiding a worksheet
I'm using Excel 2021, and I've noticed that when I hide a worksheet, Excel doesn't update the formulas. I have formulas that depend on the number of hidden worksheets, and I need them to update automatically. How can I ensure that Excel updates these formulas when worksheets are hidden or unhidden?
I have already tried to make the functions volatile but it has no effect.

Go to Formulas -> Calculation Options and make sure that is set to Automatic.

Are the sheets hidden manually or programmatically?

@BigBen the sheets are hidden manually

@dwirony already checked that, it has no effect.

You might be able to leverage one of the workbook-level events, maybe Workbook.SheetDeactivate. I'm not sure if an application-level event is feasible, might be.

Assuming you are hiding/showing the sheets by right-clicking on their tabs to show the menu that includes 'Hide' and 'Unhide' etc, you can use my code at this SO answer and, from the WorkbookActivated() "event" call Application.Calculate (or whatever code you want). This works because the menu that pops up "deactivates" Excel and when the menu disappears then Excel is "activated" again. Your functions may have to be volatile for this to work and, testing on my device, there is a short lag between showing/hiding the sheet and the formula calc

Can you share some code or formula with concrete example what is the exact state of the problem?

Another approach also based on standard events.
You can use the SheetActivate and SheetDeactivate events of a workbook to control the hiding/unhiding of worksheets, along with the collection in which the visibility state of the worksheets is stored.
In the first sheet, there are calls to 2 functions: HideCounter() and CountVisibleSheets(), which display the number of operations to hide the sheet (since the beginning of the session) and the number of visible sheets.   Alternatively, you can use a macro to enter these values into the worksheet as numbers.
Code placed in the standard module:
Public cnt As Long
Public vissheets As New Collection
Function CountVisibleSheets() As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Application.Volatile
    For Each sh In Worksheets
        If sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            CountVisibleSheets = CountVisibleSheets + 1
        End If
    Next sh
End Function

Function HideCounter() As Long
    Application.Volatile
    HideCounter = cnt
End Function

Code placed in the workbook module:
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 '   cnt = Arkusz1.Range("A1").Value
    cnt = 0
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In Worksheets
        vissheets.Add sh.Visible, sh.CodeName
    Next sh
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal sh As Object)
    If sh Is Arkusz1 Then Exit Sub
    If vissheets(sh.CodeName) = xlSheetHidden Then
        vissheets.Remove sh.CodeName
        vissheets.Add sh.Visible, sh.CodeName
        MsgBox sh.Name & " is now visible"
     '   Arkusz1.Range("A2").Value = CountVisibleSheets
        Application.Calculate
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal sh As Object)
    If sh.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
        vissheets.Remove sh.CodeName
        vissheets.Add sh.Visible, sh.CodeName
        MsgBox sh.Name & " is hidden"
        cnt = cnt + 1
     '   Arkusz1.Range("A1").Value = cnt
     '   Arkusz1.Range("A2").Value = CountVisibleSheets
        Application.Calculate
        Arkusz1.Activate
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal sh As Object)
    vissheets.Add sh.Visible, sh.CodeName
  '  Arkusz1.Range("A2").Value = CountVisibleSheets
    Application.Calculate
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDelete(ByVal sh As Object)
    vissheets.Remove sh.CodeName
  '  Arkusz1.Range("A2").Value = CountVisibleSheets - 1
    Arkusz1.Activate
End Sub

The code names of the sheets come from the Polish version of Excel. Please change them to the appropriate ones for your language version.


You could exploit the fact that hiding a sheet will cause its neighbouring sheet to become the active sheet. And unhiding a sheet will cause the newly unhidden sheet to become the active sheet. On both occasions, the application will fire a Workbook_SheetActivate event.
Within that event handler, just call Application.Calculate. Your UDFs will need to be volatile for the sheet to recalculate.
Workbook code behind would be:
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Application.Calculate
End Sub

And here is a sample UDF:
Public Function NoOfHiddenSheets() As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long
    
    Application.Volatile
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Visible <> xlSheetVisible Then
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next
    NoOfHiddenSheets = n
    
End Function

Of course, if your workbook is complex and you don't want to be recalculating each time a sheet is activated, then you could just keep a module-level variable of the number of hidden sheets and only call the Application.Calculate method if that number has changed.
BTW, if you do ever decide to hide the sheets programmatically, then the above won't work. However, you only need to create a routine that sets the visibility of a sheet and, within that routine, just call Application.Calculate.
Here is a sample:
Public Sub HideSheet()
    If Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        SetSheetVisibility Sheet2, xlSheetHidden
    Else
        SetSheetVisibility Sheet2, xlSheetVisible
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SetSheetVisibility(ws As Worksheet, vis As XlSheetVisibility)
    ws.Visible = vis
    Application.Calculate
End Sub

